# How to detect if connection to client is already made with sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create M:N socket clients, e.g N clients and each is connected to every other node. Basicly i will run my app N times with different info about other sockets so it can connect to other running instances of the app.

First i want to accept socket connections so i create listening server:

```
public class SocketServer {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private List<ClientSocketWrapper> socketList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void start(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            ClientSocketWrapper clientSocketWrapper = new ClientSocketWrapper(clientSocket);
            clientSocketWrapper.start();
            socketList.add(clientSocketWrapper)
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        serverSocket.close();
        socketList.forEach(ClientSocketWrapper::close);
    }
}
```

Wrapper for sockets:

```
public class ClientSocketWrapper {
    private final Socket socket;
    private final PrintWriter out;
    private final BufferedReader in;
    private Thread thread;

    public ClientSocketWrapper(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void start() {
        this.thread = new Thread(this::handleSocketMessages);
        this.thread.start();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        out.println(message);
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to connect to other nodes:

```
private void startConnection(String ip, int port) {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
    ClientSocketWrapper clientSocketWrapper = new ClientSocketWrapper(clientSocket);
    clientSocketWrapper.start();
    socketList.add(clientSocketWrapper)
}
```

Now lets omit the details and lets say `start` method and `startConnection` method are running in different threads.

What can happen is:

1. Instance A has the `start` method is running, connection from instnace B is accepted, and the socket is stored in list
2. the instnace A issues connect to instnace B, that is also created and stored in the list.

However now i basicly have two socket connections that are the same, e.g connection between two instances A and B.

If both intances of the application ran on different server, i could distinquish if connection exists using the IP address of node, and check if it already exists and if yes just close redundant connection. However if both of these instances run on localhost, well their IP is localhost, and port means nothing too.

Is there some way how to check if the connection already exists? Or there is no such way if everything runs on same machine.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You'll need to figure out a way for each entity to assign a unique identifier for itself, and a protocol to communicate the id across the connection.